# Suggestion: Rename tag [symantec-endpoint-protect]

Tags: discussion

I would suggest to rename the tag [symantec-endpoint-protect](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/symantec-endpoint-protect) to [symantec-endpoint-protection](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/symantec-endpoint-protection)

I guess it was shorted due to the tag name limit (25), but I think this limit is 35 if I'a [right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/337838) ? If so I suggest to rename it to the actual product name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That one's blatantly obvious. No idea why it was ever shortened in the first place. Renamed it.